# Is <boolean expression> && statement() the same as if(<boolean expression>) statement()?

Tags: javascript, syntax, if-statement, boolean, syntactic-sugar

Are the two identical?

Suppose you have:

```
var x = true;
```

And then you have one of either:

```
x && doSomething();
```

or

```
if(x) doSomething();
```

Is there any differene whatsoever between the two syntaxes?  Did I stumble across a nice bit of sugar?

Comment: In your case result will be same.

Comment: Do you minify your code? If so, don't do this. Write clear, readable code, and let the minifier take care of the tweaks.

Comment: @user1689607 I personally find the former more concise/elegant/readable, assuming that its semantically identical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly speaking, they will produce the same results, but if you use the former case as a condition for something else, you will get dissimilar results. This is because in the case of `x && doSomething()`, `doSomething()` will return a value to signify its success.

Comment: can I use the syntax for other types of statements? They're all expressions anyway, aren't they? I mean, `var x; <boolean expr> && x = 'boolean expr was true';`.  Can any statement that would follow an `if(condition)` follow the `&&` to produce the same result, even if it doesn't involve a method call?

Comment: Any expression that evaluates to a value can be included in a boolean operation.

Comment: aren't all statements in js expressions, though?

Answer (score 6):

No, they are not identical. While `if` is a *statement*, the `AND` operator is an *expression*.

That means you could use its result in an other expression, which you can't with an if-statement:

```
var result = x && doSomething();
```

Yet, in your case both have the same effect. Use the one that is more readable and represents your program structure better; I'd recommend the if-statement.

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements and also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: @AdrienBe: What should these links tell me?

Comment: Some further reading for people interested in finding out more about javascript `statement` and `expression` you mentioned in your answer, ie. differences, keywords, and so on

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer: **No.**

### Long answer:

A stated by @Steve `x && doSomething()` is an **expression**,

whereas `if(x) doSomething();` is a **statement**,

As suggested by @Daniel Li and @Bergi, think:

- an **expression** is computed ( supposed to return a value **here** ).
- a **statement** is declared ( **not** supposed to return a value **here**, think **side-effects** ).

### Why is it confusing?

- JS allows us to write `( thatExpression );`
- JS allows us to write `thatExpression;`

both assuming some kind of `doNothingWithValueOf` statement.

### How to choose?

Do you use:

- `doSomething()` as an

  - expression , think `IsMyObjectWhatever()` or `MyObjectComputedValue()`,
  - or as a statement, think `ModifyMyObject()`

And then: Do you use `x && doSomething()` as an **expression** ?

You'll end up thinking something like `thisStatement( thatExpression );` everywhere, think:

- `()` expression,
- `;` statement.

### Then why should I choose?

- Obvious is that "It works." doesn´t stand for "It´s right".
- If less obvious is **when** it will make the difference:

  - just think `()(()())()();` *can be* **right**, `(;)` **is** *wrong*.
  - check @wwaawaw [Javascript: difference between a statement and an expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703214/javascript-difference-between-a-statement-and-an-expression?lq=1)
  - or [expressions-vs-statements post by Axel Rauschmayer](http://www.2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html)

Answer (score 1):

In a word no, the two statements are not equal, though in the specific circumstances you present the outcome is the same.

`x && doSomething();` is an expression, first the `x` evaluated, because this is an AND  and since `x` is true the second argument (`doSomething()`) is then evaluated. In this case this means that the method is executed. If `x` were false then doSomething() would not be executed as the result of the expression cannot be true.

`if(x) doSomething();` is a statement. The value of x is checked, and if it is true the scope of the if statement is executed.

I've put together this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxCLF/1/) to demonstrate (with minor modifications).

Comment: Are all expressions valid as freestanding statements?

Answer (score 0):

Let's play detective.

We'll call our first approach **Conditional Arrow Invocation** and our second approach **Traditional If Else**.

We'll create two separate cases in [jsperf](https://jsperf.com) to evaluate how these two approaches fair.

## Conditional Arrow Invocations

```
const VALUE = true;
const TEST = false;

//test 1
VALUE && !TEST && (() => {
    console.log('print me!');
})();
```

**Ops/sec result:**

1. FireFox: 65,152
2. Chrome: 129,045

## Traditional If Else

```
const VALUE = true;
const TEST = false;

//test 2
if(VALUE && !TEST) {
    console.log('print me!');
}
```

**Ops/sec result:**

1. FireFox: 65,967
2. Chrome: 130,499

## Conclusion

As you can see, performance wise there isn't a huge difference but marginally **Traditional If Else** won over Conditional Arrow Invocation most of the times by an insignificantly small number. This might have something to do with creating an implicit function on the fly.

I also realized Chrome's JavaScript is a lot faster than FireFox's JavaScript execution.

Here is the jsperf link that you can run to evaluate this for yourself.

https://jsperf.com/conditional-methods-vs-traditional-if-else/1