# Why does console.log say undefined, and then the correct value?

Tags: javascript, console.log

```
console.log("hi") gives 
undefined
hi

console.log(1+1) gives 
undefined
2
```

Whether it's a string or integer calculation, I get undefined then the correct answer.

Why do I get the undefined message?  Is there a good way to avoid it?

Comment: iv'e only noticed it on chrome personally

Comment: seeing it on firefox right now.

Comment: Chrome console shows the `undefined` second.

Comment: I think it returns the value of console.log(...).

Comment: My question is a dupe - and I updated the other one to include firefox!

Comment: Can't delete so I vote to close my own question!

Comment: I think you're trolling for that "please close/delete my question" badge. LOL

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The console will print the result of evaluating an expression. The result of evaluating `console.log()` is `undefined` since `console.log` does not explicitly return something. It has the side effect of printing to the console.

You can observe the same behaviour with many expressions:

```
> var x = 1;
undefined;
```

A variable declaration does not produce a value so again `undefined` is printed to the console.

As a counter-example, expressions containing mathematical operators do produce a value which is printed to the console instead of `undefined`:

```
> 2 + 2;
4
```

Comment: It's like calling `console.log(console.log('Hi'))` outside of the actual console.

Comment: If you would like to see the value of a variable that you just assigned, you can type a `;` followed by the variable name: `var pi = Math.PI; pi`

Answer (score 14):

The `undefined` is the return value of `console.log()`. This is the standard behavior of Chrome, Safari, and Firefox JS Consoles.

Comment: console.log() might as you're not passing in anything, but surely the param passed in shouldnt retuln an undefined ?

Comment: in JS everything is a function. If you use it as a method, you'll still get `undefined`.

Comment: @Pogrindis - Try `(function(){console.log('hi'); return 1})()`

Answer (score 6):

The console shows the return value of your input.  *console.log()* doesn't return anything, so undefined.

You could just type directly into the console to get the result.

Comment: This is true for chrome devtools

Answer (score 3):

This is because `console.log()` does not return a value (i.e. returns undefined). The result of whatever you entered to the console is first printed to the console, then a bit later the message from `console.log` reaches the console and is printed as well.

If a browser does not show the undefined, it means it has noticed that your console input only prints to the console, and so skips showing the result.

Answer (score 3):

It returns the value of `console.log(...)`.

Define two functions like this and you'll see why.

```
function functionA() {
  return 1; 
}
function functionB() {
  return;
}
```

The `functionB()` returns undefined.

[image]