# Heroku: process.env.NODE_ENV does not register as 'production' (it's registering as 'development')

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables

In my index.js code, I've checked the value of process.env.NODE_ENV variable and expected it to be 'production', but on Heroku this variable is registering a value of 'development'.

I've read that Heroku sets this value to 'production' by default, but for some reason it's still registering as 'development', even when I explicitly set the value under Config Vars it still shows it's development. Below is the condition in my index.js file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // serve production assets...
} else {
  // serve development assets...
}
```

If I change the line to...

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
```

The production assets get served up just fine on Heroku.

Any ideas on how I may get process.env.NODE_ENV to register as 'production' on Heroku?

EDIT:

Within my webpack.js file I am doing this...

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const config = {
  mode: env || 'development'
};

module.exports = {
  // some code...

  ...config, // 'development' or 'production' mode

  // more code...
}
```

I did try hard-coding this value to 'production' like so...

```
mode: env || 'production'
```

But that had no effect.

Comment: Are you doing anything like `process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'` at some time?

Comment: @Rashomon Yes, just edited my post.

Comment: Not sure whats going on sorry. I would suggest checking the value step by step. Which one fails? `config` declaration?

Comment: @Rashomon It definitely has something to do with the `config` variable. I got rid of that variable and hard-coded mode like so... `mode: 'production'`, and now it works

Comment: Nice to hear!!!

Comment: Perhaps we must use another buildpack to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with my webpack.js file, specifically this code:

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const config = {
    mode: env || 'development'
};
```

For some reason `process.env.NODE_ENV` was being set to "development". I've deleted the `config` variable and replaced it with this hard-coded value:

```
mode: 'development'
```

And now it works. Only problem is I must manually change that value before I deploy to production.

Comment: This isn't really a practical solution. It's basically avoiding the issue. I just encounter the exact same issue. In my case, it must be a valid case of this issue because I am switching from GitHub Pages to Heroku. Things like react-git-info, preval.macro and this `process.env.NODE_ENV` all work when I build with gh-pages locally but none is working when Heroku builds my project in the cloud.

Answer (score 4):

To check if the `NODE_ENV` variable is set you can open a console in your project enviroment at:

[https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/{{your-app-name}}?web-console={{your-app-name}}](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/%7B%7Byour-app-name%7D%7D?web-console=%7B%7Byour-app-name%7D%7D)

Then run `node` to execute node code from console (you can run this command in your local repo too):

```
heroku run node
```

Once node is running in terminal execute:

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV) // production
```

It should return the enviroment variable value of the project

Comment: Thanks, that returns two values... 'production' and 'undefined'. What is the second value for?

Comment: Thats a good question. Seems the returned value of the function `log`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342748/why-does-console-log-say-undefined-and-then-the-correct-value

Comment: I am also getting `production` from the Heroku console but the issue still happens. That means this approach of checking the environment does not work. Both variables actually don't match.

Comment: Holy cow I never knew about `heroku run node` - AWSM!