# brightcove player mediainfo object details not printing

Tags: video.js, brightcove

I using player object.
var player = videojs.getPlayer('videoplayer');

when console.log(player) it will be shows mediainfo object.

But when consolinging mediainfo name value it will return undefined.
console.log(player.mediainfo.name);

I will expect to show name value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are seeing is the behavior of `console.log()` displaying `undefined` as its return value.  You should see this even if you do

```
 >console.log('foo')
 foo
 undefined
```

This is explained in detail in [Why does console.log say undefined, and then the correct value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342748/why-does-console-log-say-undefined-and-then-the-correct-value)

In comparison, you can also see that `undefined` is not printed if you just enter:
`player.mediainfo.name` into the console. For example, this is the output on one of our sample players in our docs:

```
>player.mediainfo.name
"Displaying a Pre-Roll Ad in a Brightcove Player"
```

But you will see `undefined` after this using `console.log()`

```
>console.log(player.mediainfo.name)
Displaying a Pre-Roll Ad in a Brightcove Player
undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to get `mediainfo` before it's populated. Once the player has loaded it then fetches the video from Brightcove's Playback API, then sets `mediainfo` and loads the video source. Try

player.on('loadstart', function() {
     console.log(player.mediainfo.name);
   });