# Getting UNDEFINED at the end of a simple for loop function BEGINNER JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, loops

```js
const reverseArray = (words) => {
  for (let i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(`${words[i]}`);
  }
};

const sentence = ['sense.', 'make', 'all', 'will', 'This'];

console.log(reverseArray(sentence))

// Should print ['This', 'will', 'all', 'make', 'sense.'];

const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(reverseArray(nums));

// Should print 5,4,3,2,1
```

But it keeps giving me Undefined at the end ? I know this is a rookie question , sorry.

Comment: Change the function so it returns the reversed array instead of logging it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined)

Comment: Your code is basically `const reverseArray = (words) => {
  for (let i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(`${words[i]}`);
  }
  return undefined;
};`

Comment: There are already several answers for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined

Comment: @Love2Code that is not the same.... This is not the extra log line in the console from executing console.log()

Comment: @epascarello It is somewhat the same problem, as well as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342748/why-does-console-log-say-undefined-and-then-the-correct-value

Comment: No.............. The person is literally logging undefined....

Comment: Without returning anything `console.log(reverseArray(sentence))` is basically the same as `console.log(undefined)`, but it just happens to be running a function also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is without a return, the function is returning nothing, which means `undefined`. So your `console.log(reverseArray(sentence))` call is the same as `console.log(undefined)`.

In this answer, the function just returns the reversed array.

```js
const reverseArray = (words) => {
  reversed = []
  for (let i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     reversed.push(words[i])
  }
  return reversed
};

const sentence = ['sense.', 'make', 'all', 'will', 'This'];

console.log(reverseArray(sentence))

// Should print ['This', 'will', 'all', 'make', 'sense.'];

const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(reverseArray(nums));
```

Comment: The code is correct here, but see my answer for more details.

Comment: imvain2 , this was the correct response and it makes sense so i'm creating a reversed var as an empty array and returning the loop to that. 

Got it , I was close but not quite there. Thank you community for the help. This was my first question.

The built in method .reverse would have worked also

Comment: You can still vote on other answers, also you can look up these kind of questions.

Answer (score 3):

It prints undefined in the end because you are trying to console.log function but it returns nothing there is no need for the console.log you can just call this function.

```
reverseArray(sentence)
reverseArray(nums)
```

But better way to reverse an array is to use build-in function reverse()
So you can change your function like this.

```
const reverseArray = (words) => {
  words.reverse().forEach(item => {
    console.log(item);
  });
};
```

Comment: The function is not correct. It does not reverse the array, nor returns anything. And if nothing is returned then it's not even considered a function, it's basically a method which is logging the array. See my answer.

Comment: @Zunair It reverse the array.

Comment: I meant in the question the reverseArray does not reverse the array.

Comment: @Zunair I am not a big expert in js, but if I define: function myFunction() {}. Can I call it a function if it doesn't return anything?

Comment: @Zunair Yes, you are right technically function doesn't reverse the array. Updated the comment. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Well technically in js method is a function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain for better understanding.

Comment: I think @blight231 is trying to learn how to make a function which reverses an array. We should guide how to do that and we can show what should be the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your reverseArray function doesn't return an array or anything hence undefined.

And it doesn't reverse your array and does not store it anywhere.

You need to reverse the array into a variable then return it at the end of the function.

Or just use built-in string.reverse() method to reverse the array!

Answer (score -1):

Every function in JavaScript returns undefined unless you return something else.

Try:

```
const reverseArray = (words) => {
  for (let i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     console.log(`${words[i]}`);
  }
  return "" //Here magic occurs
};

const sentence = ['sense.', 'make', 'all', 'will', 'This'];

console.log(reverseArray(sentence))

// Should print ['This', 'will', 'all', 'make', 'sense.'];

const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(reverseArray(nums));
```

Comment: If it does not return anything, it's called a method.

Comment: it does not matter i got -1 anyway people are providing answers that he did not ask..

Comment: You can edit the answer and explain a bit more - just say see comment below. Not everyone reads each line. I like your way, since it's makes them figure it out.