# Why does console return undefined asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, firefox, console.log

I have 2 **console.log** commands in the multiline firefox console and I execute them **(cntrl+enter)**. It looks like there is only 1 **undefined** return value but this value is either after the first log or the second log - (*I assume it is random or 'asynchronous'*). Aside: during the question my tab crashed in firefox - seemingly the second time I've seen this recently.

```
console.log("hello")
console.log("sailor")
```

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342748/why-does-console-log-say-undefined-and-then-the-correct-value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does console.log say undefined, and then the correct value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342748/why-does-console-log-say-undefined-and-then-the-correct-value)

Comment: @JustRaman I don't think it answers the question. Seemingly, firefox and google chrome behave diff in this regard. Chrome doesn't have a multiline mode, although you can do multiline commands (shift+enter). Chrome just returns undefined after the 2 command logs. I was looking at this spec - https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger which i got from https://nicolaschevobbe.com/2019/01/17/webconsole-2018-retrospective.html

Comment: @JoePythonKing chrome has snippets, but I think that's unrelated to the linked answer JustRaman gave.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Try reporting it to the FF team.