# Extracting Price as a Variable Using Google Tag Manager from Specific Page Element

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, google-tag-manager

I'm aiming to retrieve the price value (`$278.45`) from a designated HTML element using Google Tag Manager and store it as a variable for further use.

Target Element:

```
<div class="sc-fbgIAx CmZAI pricing-summary-row">
    <span class="sc-dxUwTY BLzzV">Total Due Now (USD):</span>
    <span data-testid="total-due" class="sc-dxUwTY BLzzV">$278.45</span>
</div>
```

I've made an attempt using JavaScript within GTM:

```
var totalDueElement = document.querySelector('[data-testid="total-due"]').textContent;
```

However, I haven't been successful in retrieving the value. Could someone please provide a solution and explain the correct approach? I'm seeking guidance on how to capture similar values effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "Custom Javascript" variable you should use function that'll return your variable.

In your case:

```js
function returnRevenue () {
    return document.querySelector('[data-testid="total-due"]').textContent;
}
```

It will return `'$278.45'` in your case.

Comment: Thank you! I can see in debug mode this is working. I'm curious though, when I try to run console.log(document.querySelector('[data-testid="total-due"]').textContent) in the console on the page, it returns undefined. What is different when trying to run this on page in the console for testing?

Comment: @CarsonWhitley if I understood your question correctly, you can find info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342748/why-does-console-log-say-undefined-and-then-the-correct-value)