# Why does this `do`–`while` loop repeat the last value after the end?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I tried the following code in the Google Chrome console and I’m getting this output. Why is there an additional 4 printed?

```js
var i = 0;

do{
  console.log(i);
  i++;
} while(i < 5);
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
4
```

Comment: There isn't an extra 4

Comment: that's return value, which you are mistaking for console.log. try `var i=0;do{console.log('i = ', i);i++;}while(i<5);`, you will figure it out

Comment: Run the snippet. There is nothing extra. You might just have an extra `console.log()` somewhere.

Comment: So there is an extra one when you write it in the console directly and run it?

Comment: It's just chrome console, print result of statement at last

Comment: You're seeing the result of the statement chain.

Comment: @Alex If you paste his snippet into the Javascript console you'll see the extra 4

Comment: @Barmar I'll try now

Comment: Ran in JSFiddle, nothing extra.

Comment: @Alex he is doing in chrome js console. try his snippet, you will understand the confusion

Comment: @Alex It only happens in the console. It's the console printing the value of the statement after it's done.

Comment: You should always test your logic in a fiddle or on an actual page.  That reflects 100% what will happen, and what you care about happening, in the real code.

Comment: The "result" of the `do{...} while(i<5);` loop is the "result" of the last statement in the loop body (`i++;`). Usually these are ignored but not by (Chrome's) console.

Comment: I just did it in console. Had a brainfart moment just there.

Comment: So incrementing i will cause chrome to pick up the return in the end?

Comment: `var i=0;do{i++;}while(i<5);` just run that

Comment: @Alex: No, it just the result of the last statement in the loop body.

Comment: Yes.  If you do `x = 4;` in your console, you will see it print 4.  You didn't console log that.  It's just the browser returning the result of it's last expression.

Comment: Ahh okay. Makes sense now.

Comment: @Taplar: It prints `undefined`, at least in Chrome.

Comment: I get 4 in chrome.  Or I thought I did.  wtf...  @FelixKling

Comment: Notice also that Chrome's console puts a tiny "<-" arrow next to the last `4`. This indicates the return value.

Comment: Ok `var x = 4;` is undefined  `x = 4` is 4

Comment: Here is another example: `if (true) { 5 }`. The Chrome console shows the value of the [completion record](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-completion-record-specification-type) of the statement, that's all.

Comment: `var` statements cannot be an rvalue, that's why its "return value" (according to the console, and for lack of a better word) is `undefined` and not `4`

Comment: @Alex and others: Please consider cleaning up this comment thread.

Comment: @Xufox: Good find. I felt there must be a duplicate but didn't find it.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: That's not right. `if` statements cannot be rvalues either and yet they have a "return value". The value of the a completion record of a variable declaration is explicitly set to empty: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-variable-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation

Comment: @FelixKling If I understand correctly, a completion record with [[Value]]: empty is not differentiable from [[Value]]: undefined when inspecting the value at runtime. Since both of them will evaluate to `undefined`, I fail to see why that's even relevant.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Where did you see `[[Value]]: undefined` ? The completion record of an `if` statement is not always `[[Value]]: undefined` if that's what you are implying. Otherwise I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @FelixKling I was not implying anything about if statements. My original assertion was that `var` statements have a return value of `undefined` while you "corrected" that assertion by saying it was actually [[Value]]: empty, which evaluates to `undefined` anyway.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Ah got it. That was not my point (don't care about `empty` vs `undefined`). I understood your comment that you were implying that `var` statements result in `[[Value]]: undefined` *because* they cannot be rvalues. And I just wanted to clarify that this is not reason (because there are other non-rvalue constructs that result in `[[Value]]: whatever`. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @FelixKling OH that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification, and sorry for the misunderstanding as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no extra 4 at end. Your loop is correct and works just fine :). That's return value of the `i++` expression, which you are mistaking for `console.log` in developer console. Try this, you will figure it out;

```js
var i=0;do{console.log('i = ', i);i++;}while(i<5);
```

**Edit** Thanks to @ggorlen for pointing this out, it's the return value of last expression in block(`{}`) which is `i++`, `i` increments the value and returns it's last value (if i = 4; `i++` returns 4 and makes value of i = 5), (`++i`, returns 5 and makes value of i = 5)

```
var i=0;do{console.log('i = ', i);++i;}while(i<5);
```

will give return value of 5

Comment: I would say: `var i=0;do{console.log(i);i++;}while(i<5);` returns `4` and that is the last one :)

Comment: Specifically, it's the return value of the `i++` statement, to be clear. Try it in the console: `var i = 0; i++;` output will be `0` and the value stored in `i` will be 1.

Comment: Vouching with @Andrew

Comment: Hi, can you also say what you mean by return value.

Comment: @nandukk expression often have a value when an expression execution ends. like `true` is an expression with return value of `true`. (3 && 4) is an expression with a return value of 4. The return value are used in conjunction to create powerful logic. Read more about it in your js journey :)

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for that hat-tip. I edited my answer to reflect that :+1:

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has the concept of ["Completion Records"](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-completion-record-specification-type). Basically every statement produces a completion record.

> The Completion type is a Record used to explain the runtime propagation of values and control flow such as the behaviour of statements (break,  continue, return and throw) that perform nonlocal transfers of control.

You usually cannot do anything with these in user land code, but the runtime needs those to properly execute your program. However the Chrome console will print the value of the completion record of the last statement it executes.

Without going into to much details, here is what happens:

- [The value of the completion record of the `do...while`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-do-while-statement-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation) loop is the value of the completion record of its body.
- The body is a **block** with a **statement list**. The value of the completion value of a statement list is [the value of the completion record of the last statement in the list](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-block-runtime-semantics-evaluation).
- The last statement is an **expression statement** (`i++;`). [The value of the completion record of an expression is the value the expression evaluates to](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-expression-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation).

---

The simplest example to demonstrate this behavior is simply

```
42;
```

The result of evaluating this expression *statement* is a completion record that looks something like

```
{
  type: normal,
  value: 42,
  target: empty
}
```

You will see it print `42` in the console because that's the value of the completion record of the expression statement.

A slightly more evolved example:

```
if (true) {
  42;
}
```

will print the same.

Comment: Because `42` returns `42`, that's why we get `42`, lmao :)

Comment: @Andrew: Extended it a bit so that the point becomes clearer.

Comment: Can I *quick* understand your answer like this: `console.log(do{...}while(...))` prints `4`?

Comment: @Andrew: Not quite, because that's not syntactically valid. But if there was a magically equivalent to `console.log` that prints completion records then `printCompletion do{...}while(...)` would print `{type: normal, value: 4, target: emtpy}`. Chrome pulls out the `value` of that and prints it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's normal that extra 4.
It's called **expression evaluation**. Id doesn't mean it's printing, but instead evaluating `i` to you.

Check [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/expressions) to know more about it.

This is just chrome helping you to know the dynamic environment of your variables.