# Expressions and Arguments in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and I've gone far for now. But there's only one thing that is still bothering me in this language!

What's the difference between an expression and an argument? Are they likewise the same or are they completely different?

Comment: They do not seem like the same thing to me. [Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions) and [Arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) What makes you think they are the same/similiar?

Comment: Perhaps you have an example to provide some context for your confusion?  You may simply be mis-using the terminology.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703214/javascript-difference-between-a-statement-and-an-expression I think it is answered here

Comment: Is an Expression a statement?

Comment: @Gregory There is a type of statement in javascript which consists only of an expression, yes