# Should I follow Visual Studio Code suggesting a convert to named function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I use the arrow function style quite alot in my ReactJS apps (all of them use functional style with hooks).

```
const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    doStuff(e.keyCode);
}
```

Visual Studio Code keeps suggesting here, that I use a named function like:

```
function handleKeyDown(e) {
    doStuff(e.keyCode);
}
```

What's best practice here? I have read, that arrow function and named function are equivalent in javascript. Is this not true? Does using named function have any benefit here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends, in the majority of cases they do the same (arrow or named functions) BUT they have a difference, the arrow function doesn't have `this`, so it will look for in the closes parent scope that he can find it, but named functions have their own context.

Honestly, I don't know why VSCode is proposing that change, but depending if you are using class components or functional components using arrow functions can be better.

note, I don't use class components now, but this example is for the people still using that.

```js
import React from 'react';

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._clickHandlerNamed = this._clickHandlerNamed.bind(this);
    this.myText = 'Some text';
  }

  _clickHandlerNamed(e) {
    console.log(this.myText);
  }

  _clickHandlerArrow = e => console.log(this.myText);

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this._clickHandlerNamed}>Named Function</button>
        <button onClick={this._clickHandlerArrow}>Arrow Function</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As you see in the constructor we are overriding the original `this._clickHandlerNamed` with a new function that instead of having his own  `this` context, is using the context of the parent class, and this allows to access the `this.myText` property of the `SomeComponent` component.

Arrow functions don't have context, so is going to look for the closest `this` in the tree, so should be able to access the `this.myText` property.

Comment: Yes my whole app is functional. I am also defining the app like `const app = (props) => {}` (there VSC is suggesting the same change). Thus I don't need `this`. That's why I generally use arrow functions and have not noticed any obstacles concerning the scope.

Comment: keep doing that because in functional components there's no need to use this, never

Comment: @user6329530 you're saying app is functional but you're avoiding using actual `function`s  you know that sounds silly right?!

Comment: @Vitim.us ... what

Comment: I just want to know _why_ vscode suggests things like this, I can't use "Refactor..." -> "Move to a new file" until I first convert to a named function...

Answer (score 16):

There are two major differences.

The first:

```js
function handleKeyDown(e) {
    doStuff(e.keyCode);
}
```

Here you're using a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) (or *function statement*); in the case of arrow function:

```js
const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    doStuff(e.keyCode);
}
```

You're using a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function). In fact, they're called *arrow function expressions* (since there is not an "arrow function declaration", their nature is to be an expression).

So to be clearer, the arrow function version it's more like:

```
const handleKeyDown = function(e) {
  doStuff(e.keyCode);
}
```

So the first difference is *function declarations* vs *function expression*, ( and therefore the difference between statement and expression: [Javascript: difference between a statement and an expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703214/javascript-difference-between-a-statement-and-an-expression/12703326#12703326))

For what concerns the functions, *function declarations* are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) where *function expressions* are not. That's meaning that a code like that:

```
handleKeyDown({keyCode: 13});

function handleKeyDown(e) {
    doStuff(e.keyCode);
}
```

Is perfectly valid (and running), where a code like that:

```
handleKeyDown({keyCode: 13});

const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    doStuff(e.keyCode);
}
```

Will raise an exception because `handleKeyDown` is not initialized yet.

Another difference between function expression and function declarations was that a function expression it was anonymous (unnamed). This is not valid anymore since the js engine is now able to determined the name associated with them:

```js
const foo = () => {}
const bar = function() {}

console.log(foo.name) // "foo"
console.log(bar.name) // "bar"
```

However, the difference between *arrow functions* and *function expressions*, in this case, is that you can override it:

```
const bar = function baz() {};

console.log(bar.name) // baz
```

It's important to notice, however, that the name `baz` is scoped to the function's body block. It means is not available outside:

```
const bar = function baz() {
            console.log("my name is:", baz.name)
          }

console.log(bar.name) // "baz"
bar() // "my name is: baz"
baz() // ReferenceError: bar is not defined
```

This can be useful when you want to have a recursive function without pollute the outer scope with it. Common examples are [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

```js
setTimeout(function foo() {
  doStuff();
  let time = calcNewTime();
  setTimeout(foo, time)
}, 1000);
```

or a [RequestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame):

```js
requestAnimationFrame(function render() {
  updateCoordinates();
  renderGameScene();
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
});
```

Said that, the second major difference using *arrow functions expressions* instead of functions (expression or statement) is the nature of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) itself. MDN has a neat list:

1. Does not have its own bindings to this or super, and should not be used as methods.
2. Does not have `arguments` (object), or new.target keywords.
3. Not suitable for `call`, `apply` and `bind` methods, which generally rely on establishing a scope.
4. Can not be used as constructors.
5. Can not use `yield`, within its body.

The reason why they're not suitable for `call`, `apply` and `bind` is because they use the contextual object of the enclosing scope when defined; basically they don't have a `this` on their own. It's well seen when you use them as event handlers:

```js
const obj = {
  handleClick() {
    console.log("I clicked ", this)
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", obj.handleClick);
button.click(); // "HTMLButtonElement"
```

Where:

```js
const obj = {
  handleClick: () => {
    console.log("I clicked ", this)
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", obj.handleClick);
button.click(); // "Window", assuming you execute this code in a browser
```

To sum up, where there is definitely an area of overlapping between every way to define a callable function, each of them has its own characteristics to known in order to use them correctly, and avoid possible nasty bugs.

Comment: Seconding @ZERO here; IMHO their answer is better than the accepted one.