# Conditional expressions instead of if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax, conditional-expressions

As I understand

`b && "" !== b && (a[b] = this);`

is just the same as

`if(b && "" !== b)
   a[b] = this;`

Are these syntax forms equivalent?

Comment: Yes. However, the `if` statement is easier to understand.

Comment: simple note : if you are using if(b) it will check for three conditions - whether b is null or undefined or empyt i.e "" and if it is boolean it checks for true or false

Comment: exact duplicate of [Is <boolean expression> && statement() the same as if(<boolean expression>) statement()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12664230/1048572) @FelixKling could you close it?