# What does expression && expression syntax mean?

Tags: javascript, short-circuiting

What does this line `parent && (this.parent.next = this);` mean?
It just looks like its sitting there, doing nothing, not an if statement or a promise or anything. Is there a name for this style of coding?

```
    var Particle = function(i, parent)
{
    this.next = null;
    this.parent = parent;
    parent && (this.parent.next = this);
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.src = "http://www.dhteumeuleu.com/images/cloud_01.gif";
    this.speed = speed / this.radius;
}
```

Its in multiple places in this animation file I'm looking at. Here's another example.. `(!touch  && document.setCapture) && document.setCapture();`

```
this.down = function(e, touch)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var pointer = touch ? e.touches[0] : e;
    (!touch && document.setCapture) && document.setCapture();
    this.pointer.x = pointer.clientX;
    this.pointer.y = pointer.clientY;
    this.pointer.isDown = true;
```

Comment: See also [What is “x && foo()”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6970346/1048572) and [Is <boolean expression> && statement() the same as if(<boolean expression>) statement()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12664230/1048572)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's shorthand for

```
if (parent) {
    this.parent.next = this
}
```

Comment: A very maintenance-friendly shortcut at that.

Comment: not really much shorter

Comment: Still cool, I didn't know about this.

Comment: Exactly. In javascript any expression can be evaluated logically. Since && is a binary operator with short-circuit, if the first expression evaluates to false (there are several things that in javascript evaluate to that) then the right part of the && is not executed.

Comment: How is it an advantage? It's only 3 characters shorter?

Comment: There is no advantage. It just makes it harder to follow when others maintain/read your code.

Comment: I guess minifiers would use this kinda shorthand

Comment: The advantage is that it's one line instead of three, a single expression instead of a statement with sub-statement, and a less visually complex syntactic form. In other words, it makes it **easier** to follow when you or others maintain/read your code.

Comment: @Leushenko `if(parent) this.parent.next = this;`. There: now it is one line and less visually complex than that weird boolean expression. Since assignment is fundamentally a statement (it creates side effects), it is a bad idea in most cases to try to shoehorn it into an expression, so that last point is moot.

Answer (score 7):

if parent is false then not eject (this.parent.next = this), example:

```
parent = false;
parent && alert("not run");
```

Short-Circuit Evaluation:

As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, is named "short-circuit" evaluation,

```
variable && (anything); // anything is evaluated if variable = true.
variable || (anything); // anything is evaluated if variable = false
```

it's possible to use for assignment of variables:

```
var name = nametemp || "John Doe"; // assignment defaults if nametemp is false
var name = isValid(person) && person.getName(); //assignement if person is valid
```