# Multiple effects in `else` using ternary operator

Tags: javascript

I have the next condition in Java Script:

```js
if(a === 10) {
  getName()
  getLastName()
}
```

I want to write this code using ternary operator, and i wrote this:

```js
a === 10 && (getName() && getLastName())
```

But this does not work.

 Question: What could be the issue with my code?

Comment: What returns `getName`?

Comment: please add the wanted result and the missing pieces.

Comment: "*I want to write this code using ternary operator*" - [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29659521/1048572). Also that's not the ternary conditional operator, it's an AND operator.

Comment: Is there any possibility that `getName` return empty `string`. In JS empty `string` is considered as false

Comment: @NikitaMadeev, it is a function, does not matter, i tried to simulate my issue. And i want to see if it is possible to add many result  in ternary operator, like these 2 functions for example. There could be anything.

Comment: @AskMen return value affects operator `&&`

Comment: if `getname()` returns `true` only then `getlastname()` would be called  -   this is what your 1-line code means

Comment: The syntax for a ternary operator can easily be found by googling "javascript ternary operator". Please read one of the many explanations and examples available on the web.

Comment: This is not a ternary operator. It's not even the conditional operator

Answer (score 0):

> I want to write this code using ternary operator

That's not a ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands), it's the `&&`, which is a binary operator (an operator accepting two operands). The only ternary operator in JavaScript right now is the *conditional operator* (`condition ? valueIfTruthy : valueIfFalsy`).

The problem is that when you combine things with `&&`, the right-hand operand is only evaluated if the left-hand operand's value is truthy. I guess `getName` is returning something falsy, which is why the right-hand operand isn't evaluated (`getLastName` isn't called). `&&` *short-circuits*.

Don't rewrite the `if`. It's perfectly clear and straightforward and easy to debug the way it is. It's not broken.

**If** you were going to use `&&` instead of `if`, you'd use the comma operator (a binary operator) for the two operations:

```
// Please don't do this
a === 10 && (getName(), getLastName());
```

The comma operator evaluates its left-hand operand, throws the result away, and then evaluates its right-hand operand and takes that result as its result.

But again: Please don't. :-)

Comment: how to return  more than one element in `if` statement?

Comment: @AskMen - That's a completely different question. If you need to return two things from a function, you typically use an object or an array. (That isn't changed by using `&&` instead of `if`.)