# short circuit with a return statement

Tags: javascript, short-circuiting

As far as I understand, short-circuiting with the logical AND && operator works like the following:

Assuming I have the expressions `a` and `b` then `a && b` is the same as `a ? b : a` since

if `a` is truthy then the result will be `b` and
if `a` is falsy then the result will be `a` (without even trying to resolve `b`)

That being the case why is the following (demo) code throwing a SyntaxError:

```
var add = function(a,b) {
  b && return a+b; // if(b) return a+b
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to short circuit with a return statement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `&&` binary operator needs both parts to be *expressions*.

`return something` is a statement but not an expression (it doesn't produce a value, as a value wouldn't be useful when the function ends).

Just use

```
if (b) return a+b;
```

with the added benefit of an easier to read code.

Read more :

- [Expressions vs Statements](http://www.2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html)
- [the return statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-return-statement) (EcmaScript spec)
- [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) (MDN)

Answer (score 3):

No, `return` is a statement, you cannot use it as a part of an AND expression.

You can transform your code to a single `return` statement though if you need that for some reason:

```
if (b) return a+b;
/* else */ ...
```

is (more or less) equivalent to

```
return b && a+b || (...);
```

Of course, in any code that you write by hand and read with your eyes, [you should just an `if` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12664230/1048572) anyway.