# Can And and Or replace if()

Tags: javascript

I'm studying jQuery methods and see that they use `&&` and `||` statements in some really cool ways. I'm excited to implement the technique but have a quick question on usage.

Can you pretty much completely replace if():

```
if (willWrap && !this.options.wrap) return active
```

Is the code below equivalent?

```
willWrap && !this.options.wrap && return active
```

Comment: No They're not equivalent cause of the `&& return` which is incorrect.

Comment: Just try it out - the second one is a syntax error.

Comment: Reopened because while [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664230/is-boolean-expression-statement-the-same-as-ifboolean-expression-stat) addresses the `&&` issue, it does not address the issue of using `return`which is an important part of this question.

Comment: If you are interested in self-obfuscating your code, just check out the output of uglify or some other minifier, and you will find plenty of examples to mimic. For instance, you could write `return willWrap && !this.options.wrap ? active : (foobar(), !1);`.

Answer (score 1):

No. `&&` requires expressions and `return active` is a full statement, not an expression.

```
> willWrap && !this.options.wrap && return active
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return(…)
```

Comment: What if the return active were simply active? Sorry I've been looking at this on a trip and don't have access to my computer to test.

Comment: @Tyler `return` has it's specific mean: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return IF you omit the `return` statement than your function has nothing to return, rather executes something, but that changes the way a function operates.

Comment: Oh duh. In my specific example it ends the function that it's a part of with a value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[`return`<sup>*MDN Docs*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) is always used for a specific task, and that's:

- `return;` → **break the execution** returning the function as `undefined`
- `return myResult;` → **return a value**.

If you're calling a function and expecting it to `return` *something* (a String, Number, Boolean, another function call etc...)
than you might not need the `if` statement (which is always more readable), instead you could use a [Conditional Operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) :

```
// EXAMPLE 1: Return a/b value using Conditional Operator

function example1( statement ) {
  return statement ? "FOO" : "BAR" ;
  // return "FOO"(if condition is true), else return "BAR"
  // Or use undefined instead of "BAR" if you don't want to provide a return value
}

// EXAMPLE 2: Return a/b value using Array and Boolean-to-numeric conversion

function example2( statement ) {
  return ["FOO","BAR"][!+statement];
}

// EXAMPLE 3: Return value or undefined

function example3( statement ) {
  return ["FOO"][!+statement];
}

console.log( example1(true && true) );  // "FOO"
console.log( example1(true && false) ); // "BAR"

console.log( example2(true && true) );  // "FOO"
console.log( example2(true && false) ); // "BAR"

console.log( example3(true && true) );  // "FOO"
console.log( example3(true && false) ); // undefined
```

Not logical as it might seem, since you did not wrapped your `return` inside an `if` you cannot add more code after the appearance of `return`

```
function example1( statement ) {
  return statement ? "FOO" : "BAR" ;
  // Cannot put more code here
}
```

vs:

```
function example1( statement ) {
  if(statement) {
       return "FOO";
  }
  // More code here
}
```