# Javascript Performance: `if (a in b) {b[a]()}` vs `a in b && b[a]();` vs object traversing

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I noticed I can use `a && b();` as a shorthand for `if(a) {b()}` or `if(a) b();`. The MOST usual case for this indecision is for objects having 4-5 elements.

Question: is there a performance gain/loss for using the shorthand when compared with an iteration of `if(){}` or regular object traversing `for (var i in b) { b[i]() }` ?

As suggested: some code

```
var b = { x: 20, y: 30 }, // sample object
    fn = function(v){ return v+5; }, // sample function
    endValue = 0; // some lol

// go through all elements via if
if ('x' in b) { endValue += fn(b['x']); }
if ('y' in b) { endValue += fn(b['y']); }

//go through all elements via shorthand
('x' in b) && (endValue += fn(b['x'])); 
('y' in b) && (endValue += fn(b['y']));

//go through all elements via object traversing
for (var i in b) {
  endValue += fn(b[i]);
}
```

I would assume there could be very very negligible performance differences, I need to use the above shorthand method to have a very specific order of the object elements into the computing of `endValue`.

Comment: Why don't you benchmark if yourself and see?

Comment: What does this have to do with iteration/enumeration?

Comment: I did all tests with conditionals and object traversing, I never tried the shorthand yet, currently working on it, I wish to know if it's worth the effort, it's alot of code to read.

Comment: @Bergi I don't actually know what is called a list of consecutive `if`s.

Comment: Minifiers tend to convert some statements to this to reduce size. I think the performance would be negligible, but doesn't answer your question. I recommend sticking with the use of if statements for readability.

Comment: @thednp: I don't see any lists of consecutive statements in your question. Please post actual code; otherwise I'm tempted to close as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12664230/1048572)

Comment: *"it's alot of code to read"* why would it be a *lot* of code? Although it's not entirely clear how you are relating `if` to traversing an object

Comment: Hold on, I am writing some sample code.

Comment: @Bergi I edited the question, added some sample code and a reason why I need the shorthand.

Comment: @thednp: Your shorthand seems to miss the `&&` operator

Comment: @Bergi indeed, updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a performance gain/loss for using the shorthand when compared with an `if(){}`?

No. With any decent compiler they perform absolutely the same. You should however use the `if` statements for readability and conciseness.

> Is there a performance gain/loss for using an iteration of if(){} vs regular object traversing `for (var i in b) { b[i]() }`?

That cannot really be compared as they are doing fundamentally different things, and assuming they have the same outcome the performance depends a lot on the actual objects you pass in and their properties. Use the one whose behaviour you need.

Comment: Just FYI: I finished testing and it seems object traversing is faster than the other two, no matter what. Perhaps a 10-15% performance loss.

Answer (score 0):

closure compiler by google extensively uses shorthand codes and from benchmarks there was minor to none performance gains. https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home