# javascript: left-merge two objects using EcmaScript 6 / immutable js

Tags: javascript, object, merge, ecmascript-6, immutable.js

I work in javascript Project.

I'm now about search after option to merge two objects, as the second object will only ovveride fields of the first object and not add new fields which the second not has.

Something like:

```
const firstObj = {name:'jon', age:'6}
const secondObj = {name:'nir', mark:'100%'}

const mergedObj = leftMerge(firstObj, secondObj);
```

So I like mergedObj to be:

```
{name:'nir', age:'6'}
```

Is I have any way to do that with javascript (I worl with EcmaScript 6), or with immutable.js library?

Answer (score 3):

There's not builtin for this ([`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) merges *all* properties), but you can write it really easily yourself:

```
function leftMerge(a, b) {
    const res = {};
    for (const p in a)
        res[p] = (p in b ? b : a)[p];
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate `firstObj` keys, and take the values from `secondObj` if it has those properties, if not take the values from `firstObj`:

```js
const firstObj = {name:'jon', age:'6'}
const secondObj = {name:'nir', mark:'100%'}

const leftMerge = (a, b) => Object.keys(a).reduce((r, key) => (r[key] = (key in b ? b : a)[key], r), {});

const mergedObj = leftMerge(firstObj, secondObj);

console.log(mergedObj);
```

Comment: I'd recommend to drop the `Object.assign` and make that ([horrible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12664230/1048572)) `if` an `if`-`else` statement

Comment: @Bergi - Thanks for the better logic.