# Beginner JavaScript - Complexity of code is 16 in VS Code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning JavaScript. I was playing around and wrote a function to find the largest integer. It works just fine, but I was wondering how I can DRY it up.

```
function largerInt(int1, int2, int3, int4) {
  if (int1 > (int2 && int3 && int4)) {
    console.log(int1);
  } else if (int2 > (int1 && int3 && int4)) {
      console.log(int2);
    } else if (int3 >(int1 && int2 && int4)) {
      console.log(int3);
    } else if (int4 >(int1 && int2 && int3)) {
      console.log(int4);
    }
  

}
```

Comment: You mean the largest number between int1, 2, 3, 4?

Comment: Sidenote, `(int1 > (int2 && int3 && int4)` doesn't do what you think it does. [Is <boolean expression> && statement() the same as if(<boolean expression>) statement()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12664230) | [What is “x && foo()”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6970346) | [Javascript AND operator within assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3163407)

Comment: "*It works just fine"* so, have you tried `largestInt(2, 3, 1, 0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using too many `if` and `else` and your function works only with exactly 4 parameters. It's much better to make it work with any number of parameters and be more straight forward:

```
function largerInt(...nums) {
  if (nums.length === 1) {
    return nums[0];
  }
  let largestNum = nums[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (largestNum > nums[i]) {
      largestNum = nums[i];
    }
  }

  return largestNum;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, as I actually needed a loop answer but forgot to mention it.

Answer (score -1):

If you need the largest number then try this-

```js
const largeInt = (...nums) => Math.max(...nums);
console.log(largeInt(3, 4, 2, 9));
```

Comment: If they're struggling with conditions then it's very likely introducing arrow functions and spread syntax isn't going to help them understand why *their* approach isn't working.

Comment: But he is asking about DRY code, and he may learn from it. Don't worry. @AndrewLi

Comment: @SajeebAhamed It works perfectly, thank you for your help. And thank you all for helping as well.

Comment: @HammadKhalid please accept the answer if it helps you and don't forget to upvote so that other can get help.